Syntax of "filter" param in Azure Code Search API
The Azure Code Search API defines the request body param filter as such :
filters 
object

Filters to be applied. Set it to null if there are no filters to be applied.

and provides a single example as well :
POST https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=7.0

{
  "searchText": "CodeSearchController",
  "$skip": 0,
  "$top": 1,
  "filters": {
    "Project": [
      "MyFirstProject"
    ],
    "Repository": [
      "MyFirstProject"
    ],
    "Path": [
      "/"
    ],
    "Branch": [
      "master"
    ],
    "CodeElement": [
      "def",
      "class"
    ]
  },
  "$orderBy": [
    {
      "field": "filename",
      "sortOrder": "ASC"
    }
  ],
  "includeFacets": true
}

I can't find the exhaustive syntax of said filter param. Can anyone point me in the right direction by any chance?
Thanks!

To be more specific : I want to build a query to search all repositories that contain Kotlin files.

The specific syntax for the filter parameter isn't exhaustively documented in the Azure Code Search API reference. You can check similar ticket.
You may follow the given example to structure the request body, including the filters object. Or actually you can also find the api in network trace(F12) with detail request body.

To search all repositories that contain Kotlin files, you can skip filter, search ext:kt as below, simply copy the request body to rest api.


Thanks, this helps a lot! Kinda weird to not actively document it, but mention it in the docs on Microsoft side though.

(btw, your answer is only partly valid : your query will return all Kotlin files in a project, leading to many times the same repo being returned)

Glad to know it helps! The code search will find all kotlin files(.kt) in all repositories, if different kotlin files exist in same repo, it will list repo again for each file. If you only want a repo listed, you need to use a custom script to handle the response. The API itself doesn't show all results in one repo. :)

Yes, that's what I'm doing right now, I was semi-hoping there would be some kind of custom "unique" SQL like keyword but it doesn't look like it. Thanks!
